# Using JSON files in html

Tags: html, json

I'm have trouble to understand  how to use the data saved in a JSON file  and load it in a html page Everything locally:
say this the JSON file :

```
    { 

    "level1":{
        "level1_1":{
            "example": "test",
            "example2":"123123"
        },
        "level1_2":{
            "example": "test",
            "example2":"123123"
        }
    },

    "level2":{
        "level2_1":{
            "example": "test",
            "example2":"123123"
        },
        "level2_2":{
            "example": "test",
            "example2":"123123"
        }
    }

}
```

And I want to be able to call  the data from it, in and HTML file for example :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>reading json</title>
  <style>

  </style>

</head>
<body>

  <br>
  file value :

  <br>

<script>
function loadJSON(callback) {   

var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
xobj.open('GET', 'config.json', true); // Replace 'my_data' with the path to your file
xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
        // Required use of an anonymous callback as .open will NOT return a value but simply returns undefined in asynchronous mode
        callback(xobj.responseText);
      }
};
xobj.send(null);  
}

function init() {
 loadJSON(function(response) {
  // Parse JSON string into object
    var actual_JSON = JSON.parse(response);
 });
}
</script>

</body>
```

I've got the script from [this tutorial](https://codepen.io/KryptoniteDove/post/load-json-file-locally-using-pure-javascript) and still do get it run. 
So my aim just to see after ** first value**  data from the JSON file. 
any idea how u guys do it ?

Comment: Before `<script>` tag ends call `init();`. Before `<script>` element starts add `<div id="displaydata"></div>`. After `actual_JSON` add `document.getElementById("displaydata").innerHTML=actual_JSON;`

Comment: @fiveelements thanks for replying , can u tell  how can use the call in html file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add some id attribute in html, then select based on that id and loop the json data and insert like this

```
<!doctype html>

    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>reading json</title>
      <style>

      </style>

    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="json_result"></div>
<script>
function loadJSON(callback) {   

var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
xobj.open('GET', 'config.json', true); // Replace 'my_data' with the path to your file
xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
        // Required use of an anonymous callback as .open will NOT return a value but simply returns undefined in asynchronous mode
        callback(xobj.responseText);
      }
};
xobj.send(null);  
}

function init() {

 loadJSON(function(response) {
  // Parse JSON string into object
    var actual_JSON = JSON.parse(response); 

    for (var key in actual_JSON) {
        var innerkey = actual_JSON[key];
        for (var inner in innerkey) {
             document.getElementById('json_result').innerHTML += 'Example: '+innerkey[inner]['example']+'<br>';
             document.getElementById('json_result').innerHTML += 'Example2: '+innerkey[inner]['example2']+'<br>';
        }   
    }   
 }); 
}
init();
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: thanks for reply but your solution seems not to work for me ? here's what I get : index.html:33 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/Engine/Documents/json/config.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, brave, https

Comment: @Engine you can check by replacing the config.json with the absolute path of that file. maybe you can try this http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bZKGxFnZDS?indent=2 , i have added you json file data and generated the link

Comment: @Maher even after setting up the path i get the same  error :/

Comment: I think this the issue :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local/21608670

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more elaborate answer.

First, let's parse the `JSON` into an object.

```
var actual_JSON = JSON.parse(response);
```

Second, transform the `JSON` object into a readable string.

```
var json_string = JSON.stringify(actual_JSON, undefined, 2);
```

Then, use the `querySelector()` function to select a [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction) element. Note that `#output` means I want to select an `ID` attribute named **output**.

```
var output = document.querySelector("#output");
```

Then, I am adding by the `JSON` string to the DOM with the DOM `innerHTML` property. It will be added right after "file value".

```
output.innerHTML += json_string;
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>reading json</title>
  <style>

  </style>

</head>
<body>

  <br>
  <div id="output">file value : </div>
  <br>

<script>

// Starts.
init();

function loadJSON(callback) {   
  var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
  xobj.open('GET', 'config.json', true); // Replace 'my_data' with the path to your file
  xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
          // Required use of an anonymous callback as .open will NOT return a value but simply returns undefined in asynchronous mode
          callback(xobj.responseText);
          // init(xobj.responseText)
        }
  };
  xobj.send(null);  
}

function init() {
  loadJSON(function(response) {

    // Parse JSON string into object
    var actual_JSON = JSON.parse(response);

    // Transforms the JSON object into a readable string.
    var json_string = JSON.stringify(actual_JSON, undefined, 2);

    // Select <br> tag.
    var output = document.querySelector("#output");

    // Adds it to the DOM.
    output.innerHTML += json_string;
  });
}

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks for replying but can u tell how should I call a specific element in html file  file

Comment: I modified my answer and it is much more complete. I hope it helped you.

Comment: I've copied ur answer but still can't any resut ?

Comment: It works great for me. Make sure your `config.json` file is in the same directory as your `html` file.

Comment: index.html:33 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/Engine/Documents/json/config.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, brave, https.

Comment: this what I get

Comment: I think this the issue :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local/21608670

Comment: @Engine I am not an expert in `XMLHttpRequest` but I know it is possible to encounter issues like the one you have. Try the code on a web server and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

[This stack overflow question will guide you well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26008698/converting-json-to-html-with-jquery-jput)

Comment: I found your answer in the question that was asked here. Do not concentrate on the reply but on the question.